# sort character vector by multiple numbers

Tags: r, sorting, date, vector

I have a sample character vector with file names like this:

```
> vector
[1] "1 Janu 1998.txt"        "2 Feb. 1999.txt"   "3 Marc 1999.txt" 
[4] "2 February 1998.txt"    "3 March. 1998.txt" "1 Jan 1999.txt"
```

I would like to sort the elements by year and month(first number of each element). So I do this:

```
> library(gtools)
> mixedsort(vector)
[1] "1 Janu 1998.txt"    "1 Jan 1999.txt"    "2 February 1998.txt"   
[4] "2 Feb. 1999.txt"    "3 Marc 1999.txt"   "3 March. 1998.txt"
```

If I use sort(vector) I get the same output. I have been reading several questions, but I have not found a specific answer to this. I would be grateful if someone could help me. Thanks in advance.
  I would like to get the following output:

```
> output
[1] "1 Janu 1998.txt"    "2 February 1998.txt"    "3 March. 1998.txt"       
[4] "1 Jan 1999.txt"     "2 Feb. 1999.txt"        "3 Marc 1999.txt"
```

Comment: Can you give an example of the kind of output you would like?

Comment: I'm sorry but changing the input data makes this an entirely different problem/question! Plus you're being quite disrespectful towards those SO users that were trying to help based on your original sample data. What kind of and how many non-standard abbreviations for the month names do you have? How are we (and how is R) supposed to know? Previously parsing was straight-forward with `strptime`; now this becomes an issue of interpreting/mapping non-standard abbreviations for month names.

Comment: I'm so sorry, Maurits. I would like to fix my mistake. I have many non-standard abbreviations, so I was looking for a method to solve this regularly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do:

```
v <- c("1 Jan 1998.txt", "2 Feb. 1999.txt", "3 March 1999.txt", "2 Feb 1998.txt", "3 March. 1998.txt","1 Jan 1999.txt")

v[order(as.Date(gsub("\\.", "", v), "%d %b %Ytxt"))];
#[1] "1 Jan 1998.txt"    "2 Feb 1998.txt"    "3 March. 1998.txt"
#[4] "1 Jan 1999.txt"    "2 Feb. 1999.txt"   "3 March 1999.txt"
```

Explanation: We use `as.Date` to convert entries in vector `v` to dates; `order` will then properly order dates by day, month, year.

Note that some of your entries in vector `v` contain a period after the month; not sure if this is by accident, but the `gsub` command takes care of those.

The same is achieved with:

```
v[order(as.Date(gsub("(\\.|\\.txt)", "", v), "%d %b %Y"))];
```

---

### Update

To address non-standard abbreviations of month names, I would define a custom `map` that links non-standard with standard names/abbreviations. Then you can do something like this:

```
v <- c("1 Janu 1998.txt", "2 Feb. 1999.txt", "3 Marc 1999.txt",
    "2 February 1998.txt", "3 March. 1998.txt", "1 Jan 1999.txt")

# Define a map to map non-standard to standard month abbrev
map <- c(
    Janu = "Jan",
    Marc = "March")

# Separate dmy from filename and store in matrix
mat <- sapply(gsub("(\\.|\\.txt)", "", v), function(x)
    unlist(strsplit(x, " ")))

# Replace non-standard month names
mat[2, ] <- ifelse(
    !is.na(match(mat[2, ], names(map))),
    map[match(mat[2, ], names(map))],
    mat[2, ])

# Convert to Date then to numeric
dmy <- as.numeric(apply(mat, 2, function(x)
    as.Date(paste0(x, collapse = "-"), format = "%d-%b-%Y")));

# Order according to dmy
v[order(dmy)]
#[1] "1 Janu 1998.txt"     "2 February 1998.txt" "3 March. 1998.txt"
#[4] "1 Jan 1999.txt"      "2 Feb. 1999.txt"     "3 Marc 1999.txt"
```

Comment: Thank you, Maurits. You're right, some elements contain "." after the month. Another problem is that there are elements with months like: "Janu", "Fe.". I can't get the output I want. Could you show me the way to solve this?

Comment: @Citizen The period is not a problem as I demonstrate; the non-standard abbreviations for months are a different story (and a different question, since your sample data didn't show that). Generally it's absolutely critical to always provide *representative* sample data; unfortunately this didn't seem to have been the case. Non-standard abbreviations for months would require a different approach for parsing the filenames, as we cannot rely on `strptime` anymore (which does the parsing in `as.Date`).

Comment: Sorry, Maurits. I have edited the question with a better example. Thank you very much.

Comment: @Citizen I've added an update to my solution to account for non-standard month abbreviations. Please take a look. For your full data, you will have to extend `map` to account for all non-standard month names in your data.

Comment: Thank you very much, Maurits. Sorry for my mistakes.